# wrapping mysql transaction

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I have 3 mysql queries to run

```
mysql_query( "create temporary table here ");
mysql_query( "UPDATE Statement goes here ");
mysql_query( "DROP temporary table here  ") or die(mysql_error())
```

how do I wrap these in a transaction?

Answer (score 2):

You don't. DDL statements, such as `create temporary table here` are never part of a transaction in MySQL.

Comment: +1 ... [list of DDL statements here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/implicit-commit.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [mysqli_multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

```
mysqli_multi_query("CREATE ...;UPDATE Statement.. ; DROP temp ");
```

note the ; between queries.